# Request forbidden by administrative rules

Tags: eclipse, macos

I was trying to run a junit,which calls an API (https:conectapitest.company.com/consumerservice/createConsumer) ,when I was running using eclipse neon (java8) I am getting the following the error .

```
Unexpected response from Connect server:  responseCode=403, responseMessage=Forbidden responseBody=<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

The API is working when I run in postman. I am using Mac OS. Is this issue related to eclipse or MacOS?
I verified all eclipse configs ,did not change any settings ,it worked few weeks back.
while running the testcase, I noticed the message like

```
SystemProperty java.net.useSystemProxies = null defaulting to FALSE
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Eclipse Neon is more than five years and 16 releases behind. If your macOS is not that old (which is hopefully not the case), the issue is that you missed to update your Eclipse (there have been and probably always will be changes in macOS that require adaptation of the software to work properly). Please make sure your software is up to date before asking.

Comment: Thank you howlger . I am using Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500 , I am using this eclipse neon only for one project which is using bpmn workflow(activiti) and the mac version is 11.6.2. shall i update mac software or eclipse neon version?

Comment: Eclipse Neon is far too old for macOS 11.6.2. A bunch of things has been adapted for Big Sur. Use the current Eclipse (2021-12) since there is no LTS version.

Comment: Does the current Eclipse(2021-12) support BPMN flow(activiti) project?

Comment: Find it out yourself.